# How to connect Azure Redis Cache to Redsmin

Tags: azure, redis, redsmin

I don't see how to connect to Azure Redis Cache with SSL activated to my Redsmin GUI account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need your azure redis cache primary key (e.g. `TkloUGvd+Eosuqr9keFhyH+A/6wRz0lcT6V`), host (e.g. `myredis.redis.cache.windows.net`) and port (e.g. `6380`).

Thus your redis connection string will be something like this

> redis://TkloUGvd+Eosuqr9keFhyH+A/6wRz0lcT6V@myredis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380

Then you will need to extract the certificate from windows azure in PEM format you can run the above command to do so:

> openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect SERVER:SSL_PORT -prexit 2>/dev/null)

Finally just create a new "Publicly available (SSL/TLS)" server and enter both the connection string and the certificate public key et voila!

A **[step-by-step guide](https://redsmin.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/485711-how-to-connect-redsmin-to-azure-redis-cache)** is also available in Redsmin knowledge database.